# Discord bot.py file unable to load extensions [discord.py rewrite]

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've run into an issue with switching to the rewrite of discord.py. On extension loading I'm running into an ExtensionNotFound error.

I've tried different methods to get the extension to be recognized (such as using the entire directory in the code to find the folder containing cogs). Unfortunately all methods I've tried have resulted in the same ExtensionNotFound error.

Methods I've tried:

```py
STARTUP = ['cogsR.basic_repliesR']

cogs_dir = r'D:\Code-Dev\Pyhthon\DiscordStuff\Bots\ri0tbot\ri0t-bot_current_v(rewrite)\cogsR'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in [f.replace('.py', '') for f in listdir(cogs_dir) if isfile(join(cogs_dir, f))]:
        try:
            bot.load_extension(cogs_dir + "." + extension)
        except (d.ClientException, ModuleNotFoundError):
            print(f'Failed to load extension {extension}.')
            traceback.print_exc()
```

```py
STARTUP = ['cogR.basic_repliesR']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.path.insert(1, os.getcwd() + '/cogsR/')
    for extension in STARTUP:
        try:
            bot.load_extension(extension)
        except (AttributeError, ImportError) as e:
            exc = '{}: {}'.format(type(e).__name__, e)
            cprint('extension error {}\n{}'.format(extension, exc), 'red')
```

Through either of these methods the bot.py file should have been able to load the extensions in the `STARTUP` library. Instead I'm met with the following error message on file run.

```
Exception has occurred: ExtensionNotFound
Extension 'cogsR.basic_repliesR' could not be loaded.
  File "C:\Users\edmun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 620, in load_extension
    raise errors.ExtensionNotFound(name, e) from e
  File "D:\Code-Dev\Pyhthon\discordstuff\Bots\ri0tbot\ri0t-bot_current_v(rewrite)\botR.py", line 50, in <module>
    bot.load_extension(extension)
  File "C:\Users\edmun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\edmun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\edmun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

```py
'''cog: commands using a list for randomly chosen replies'''
from random import choice
import asyncio
import os

import discord as d 
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType

from utilitiesR import lists

class ListCommands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot, **kwargs):
        self.bot = bot
        self.name = kwargs.get('username')

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def rip(self, ctx):
        '''a basic rip command'''
        #await ctx.send_typing()
        #await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
        _choice = choice(lists.RIP)
        await ctx.send(_choice)


def setup(bot):
    '''cog setup'''
    bot.add_cog(ListCommands(bot))
    print('list commands ready')
```

Comment: That exception should include more information.  Is that the full exception message?  Do all of your extensions have a `setup` method?  Are you using a recent version of discord.py but not the [new cog mechanics](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/cogs.html)?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  Unfortunately this is the entire exception message I get when running the main bot file. At the moment there is a single cog and it does have a `setup` method. I'm using version 1.0.0a of the API and I believe I'm using the new cog mechanics correctly.

Comment: Could you share the content of `basic_repliesR`? Maybe some error there is preventing it from loading

Comment: @PatrickHaugh an edit has been posted

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for cog in os.listdir("./cogsR"):
        if cog.endswith(".py"):
            try:
                cog = f"cogs.{cog.replace('.py', '')}"
                bot.load_extension(cog)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"{cog} Can not be loaded")
                raise e
            else:
                print("{} has been succesfully Loaded.".format(cog))
```